# No free text with Typeahead

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

How can I disable free text input with Twitter's Typeahead plugin? All examples and configurations I find, the user can enter custom text. I need the user to NOT be able to enter custom text, but only if the text matches one of the options.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding your question but what is the point of type ahead if the user can not type?

Comment: That's a rather a-typical behavior. I'd suggest reconsidering from a usability standpoint. That said, to disable it, you'd need to re-check the input on every key-up and see if it matches the result set.

Comment: @ScottMurphy The point is to let the user type and the options will auto-complete, but it needs to be one of the options, not free text. Twitter's typeahead makes it easier for the user to select options: instead of clicking and scrolling down, they can type and select (but I need to be specific options selected, not an invented one)

Comment: I would agree with @DA in that removing characters as someone types is probably not the best idea from a usability perspective. It would be better to just let the Typeahead plugin do what it is good at and show suggestions - if nothing matches then no suggestions are shown.

Comment: The issue is that if it's a text field, the implication is that I can type whatever I want. So you probably should let them. If there are no matches, perhaps you can treat that as an error state and handle it with messaging. A common way to handle it is to not use a text field, but a drop-down with a searchable filter: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

Answer (score 4):

The technique is to use .blur to check if valid suggestion is present

```
var myData = ["sugg1" , "sugg2" ]; // all data required for typeahead

$("#search").typeahead({source : myData})
                   .blur(validateSelection);

function validateSelection() {
    if(source.indexOf($(this).val()) === -1) 
        $("#search").val("");
}
```

Comment: Is it working, I tried it a while back so I am not sure, but I did something similar for sure

Comment: same problem here, how can you handle this solution with remote and multiple data sources? cannot figure it out..